# Menu Bar with Hover Sub-Categories?

Tags: html, css, hover, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a menu bar that has 2 levels of menus.  The top menu is is the main one.  Then the second level underneath it has some sub category items.  Right now you need to click on the main menu first and load that page to get see the sub category menu items for that section because they are just hard coded into the page.  I want to make it so that when you hover over the main menu items that it will load the sub menu.

[Here is a jsFiddle of the navigation area and CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/PWFGd/)

[Here are a couple of screenshots of what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVeQU.jpg)

What would be my best method of accomplishing this.  I'm not the most experienced but I got a pretty good grasp of HTML and CSS.  Any help in the right direction would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made this type of menu in the past, I've created a copy of the code you can find here http://jsfiddle.net/PWFGd/24/

The property you want to use is:

```
selector{
  display: none;
}

selector:hover{
  display: block;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Aymeric.

Comment: I kind of got it worked out but have a few questions.  First is it possible to start the submenu all the way on the left?  See the picture.  
[http://i.imgur.com/XUFKb.png](http://i.imgur.com/XUFKb.png)  

Also, I can't seem to get my font to change like the one on top.  Where do I enter the font in at?  I tried in a bunch of different logical spots but it doesn't seem to change.  

Thanks!

Comment: Also is there a way to make one of the menu items preselected?  So when you're not hovering over it the default one will show up?

Comment: To make it start from the left you can add a negative left margin to this property => `#menu li ul`, there is certainly an other way but I made this code so long ago I can't really remember all the details.
Regarding the font you have to change it here => `#menu ul li.menu`
But I also suggest you to replace `#menu ul li.menu` by `#menu ul li.menu, #menu ul li a` so even if you don't have a sub menu your main menu will look the same.

Comment: I was able to get the font changed but I'm still stuck on the margin.  I tried adding the margin but it will not move it to the left anymore.  I can move it to the right though.  The problem too is that it moves all of them.  Here is screenshot of it on 4 of the different headings [http://i.imgur.com/pvvYa.png](http://i.imgur.com/pvvYa.png) I want them all to start right underneath where home is.  Is this possible?

Comment: Also is there a way to make one of the menu items preselected? So when you're not hovering over it the default one will show up?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a general sibling combinator (`~`) with your current structure to accomplish something like this. Use the `hover` pseudo element to toggle the display state (or visiblity) of the submenu.

http://jsfiddle.net/PWFGd/25/

```
/* on hover of mainmenu, find subnav and show it */
.mainMenu:hover ~ ul.subNav {
    display: block;
}

ul.subNav{
    display: none; /* hide submenu */
    font:normal 11px/12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding:4px 0 0 0;
}
```

There are plenty of examples on the net of css based navigation menus. I think you might want to rethink your html structure and use one of those. [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS460US460&sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=sea&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS460US460&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=css%20horizontal%20menu%20with%20submenu&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=49e91e21499bfe9d&ix=sea&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1920&bih=1115)

Answer (score 0):

@ Aymeric answer is good one, its also called "2 level horizontal navigation in CSS" i often use them in my projects,

[here is demo what u looking for](http://www.duoh.com/csstutorials/2levelmenu/index.html)

[complete tutorial link](http://veerle-v2.duoh.com/blog/comments/2_level_horizontal_navigation_in_css_with_images/)